# Syntax error when adding quote character before minus sign to fixup for csv export to Excel

Tags: r, csv, substring, paste, quoting

In my dataset I have a column where some characters start with a minus sign. This causes issues when exporting as a csv and opening in Excel. As such I would like to add a `'` for the rows where the first character is a `-`.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                 b=c("test","-test","test2","-","-test3"))
```

I've tried this but get the following error:

```
df$b[substring(df$b,1,1)=="-"] <- paste0("'",df$bsubstring(df$b,1,1)=="-")
```

> Error in paste0("'", df$bsubstring(df$b, 1, 1) == "-") :
>   attempt to apply non-function

Comment: You should try formating the target column as type = "Text". You should also ask for your money back from any book that tells you to use the construction `as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))`

Comment: The field is formatted as "chr" which I believe as text. If not can you advise? Also if I should not use as.data.frame to create a dataframe please kindly explain or link to an article that does. Thanks.

Comment: Start with typing `?cbind` and `?sub`. This will give you some starting point.

Comment: R has some issues with csv export: which csv export command are you using (`base::write.csv`?), which locale, which encoding (utf-8?), are you using quopting or escaping? Try to use the options on [`write.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)

Comment: I think you are confusing R and Excel. Excel does not have a chr-format or type. You should be able for find plenty of SO warnings against using as.data.frame(cbind(...)).

Comment: @42-: the `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` had  nothing to do with that, and I fixed up the code to not use it anyway

Comment: I didn't say that `as.data.frame(...))` had anything to do with the problem. I only meant to say it was extremely bad coding practice.

Comment: @42- Sure, sure, but let's focus on the biggest evil here: the OP is trying to manually do quoting instead of using `write.csv()`'s quoting. This is unscaleable, almost surely avoidable, and a bad way to go - millions of us export csv to Excel without an issue. If they have found a legit bug in write.csv quoting, then by all means show us what it is.

Comment: I'm guessing your entirely reasonable points are made in an earlier answer on SO. You could search for a good one and mark this as a duplicate. I'm doing this from aging memory anyway. When I replaced my system harddrive, Evil Corp security features marked my machine as different and the entire Office Suite was non-functional. (No other licensed software had this problem.) The sales/support people on the phone refused to offer any assistance. I'm using open source stuff now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `sub`

```
df$b <- sub("-", "'-", df$b)
df$b
#[1] "test"    "'-test"  "test2"   "'-"      "'-test3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
ind <- startsWith(df$b,"-")
df$b[ind] <- paste0("'",df$b[ind])
df
# a       b
# 1 a    test
# 2 b  '-test
# 3 c   test2
# 4 d      '-
# 5 e '-test3
```

Answer (score 2):

There are missing `[]` in this code `df$bsubstring`.

Try this

```
df = 
  data.frame(
    a = c("a","b","c","d","e"),
    b = c("test","-test","test2","-","-test3"), 
    stringsAsFactors = F)

df$b[substring(df$b,1,1)=="-"] <- paste0("'",df$b[substring(df$b,1,1)=="-"])

df
#  a       b
#1 a    test
#2 b  '-test
#3 c   test2
#4 d      '-
#5 e '-test3
```